# Mysql: return orderBy ranking

Tags: mysql, doctrine

Is there a way to return the Mysql orderBy ranking as part of the resulting record?

For example, lets say I have a comment table where I am querying results ranked by:

`comment_rating` and `comment_length`, using `orderBy('r.comment_rating*r.comment_length')`.

Now I want the resulting records to include the value of their respective `comment_rating*comment_length` calculations.

Is this possible?

edit: also, does doctrine perform the ranking calculations twice if I do this and also use the same algorithm for orderBy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
SELECT *, (comment_rating * comment_length) AS ranking FROM comment ORDER BY ranking DESC
```

**Edit**

Haven't used Doctrine, but after a quick glance at the [documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/hu/dql-doctrine-query-language), I guess it would be something like this:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('*, (comment_rating * comment_length) AS ranking')
    ->from('comment')
    ->orderBy('ranking');
$comments = $q->execute();
```

Comment: how would I do that using Doctrine?

Comment: @whamsicore Haven't used Doctrine, but have a look at my updated answer, and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
Select comment_rating, comment_length, 
       (comment_rating * comment_length) as rat_len 
From comment 
OrderBy rat_len
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT <yourFields>, (r.comment_rating * r.comment_length) AS Rating FROM ...
```

---

**Documentation:**
[Doctrine Query Language: Aggregate-values.](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/hu/dql-doctrine-query-language#select-queries%3aaggregate-values)

Comment: Does doctrine perform the ranking calculations twice if I do this and also use the same algorithm for orderBy?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is include

```
(comment_rating*comment_length) as comment_ranking
```

in the SELECT field list.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  comment_rating,
  comment_length,
  comment_rating*comment_length AS comment_rank
FROM
  tablename
ORDER BY
  comment_rank;
```